# apache-nifi PutSQL processor with MS-SQL: update statement hangs

Tags: sql-server, apache-nifi

System: MS-SQLServer 2016, Apache NiFi 1.11.4

The workflow for inserting records in MS-SQL with PutSQL processor works fine.

The workflow for updating records hangs:

- 2 flowfiles in queue
- PutSQL processor shows "active threat"
- but no log entry, no error message, no further worflow in success, failure or retry

[Screenshot: PutSQL processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pgc2.png)

The UODATE statement is:

```
UPDATE [MyERP].[dbo].[Cust_audit] 
SET [SYNC_SYNCED_AT] = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
[SYNC_STATUS] = 'OK' 
WHERE [SYNC_RECID] = ?
```

and the attributes are

```
sql.args.1.type=4
sql.args.1.value=373737
```

Any idea, whats going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:
In PutSQL Processor "*Support Fragmented Transactions*" was still on "**true**" but should be "**false**"

Sorry for asking stupid questions ;)